# Use alias within Where Clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, where-clause, common-table-expression

I have a BigQuery built upon a CTE.

```
With Trips AS (
    SELECT
        unique_key,
        EXTRACT(MONTH from trip_start_timestamp) AS month,
        EXTRACT(YEAR from trip_start_timestamp) AS year
    FROM
        `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
    WHERE
        year = 2017
)
SELECT
    month,
    COUNT(unique_key) AS num_trips
FROM    Trips
GROUP BY    month
ORDER BY    month
```

It gives me the error

> **00 Unrecognized name: year at [8:33]**.

After moved the Where clause outside the CTE, I got it right.

```
With Trips AS (
    SELECT
        unique_key,
        EXTRACT(MONTH from trip_start_timestamp) AS month,
        EXTRACT(YEAR from trip_start_timestamp) AS year
    FROM
        `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
)
SELECT
    month,
    COUNT(unique_key) AS num_trips
FROM
    Trips
WHERE year = 2017
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

It seems we can't use the alias directly with the Where clause at the same query. But I can use an alias with the Oder by and Group by without any problem.

Any thoughts on why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use column alias in where clause, you can repeat the expression in where clause

```
With Trips AS (
    SELECT
        unique_key,
        EXTRACT(MONTH from trip_start_timestamp) AS month,
        EXTRACT(YEAR from trip_start_timestamp) AS year
    FROM
        `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
    WHERE  EXTRACT(YEAR from trip_start_timestamp) = 2017
)
SELECT
    month,
    COUNT(unique_key) AS num_trips
FROM    Trips
GROUP BY    month
ORDER BY    month
```